# How to donwload image to gallery after FACE DETECTED in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, face-detection

I can detect faces by the help of Google's sample vision app [FaceTracker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker). What I want to do is to take photo of detected face and download it to phone Gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File imagesFolder = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , "FolderName" );
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            final File image = new File( imagesFolder , "/" + "IMG_" +System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png" );
            File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            imgCap.takePicture(image, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                    String msg = "Pic captured at " + image.getAbsolutePath();

                    //storing the image in a folder in gallery  

                    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE );
                    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile( image );
                    mediaScanIntent.setData( contentUri );
                   getActivity().sendBroadcast( mediaScanIntent );
```

Comment: What is imgCap? It shows error. Could you please modify this code so that it runs on  [FaceTracker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker) app.

Comment: imgCap is the variable of preview of the image being seen.